# HangFire doesn't like it when I register a Func in DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a class which requires a Func to be injected into its constructor. The class is called SomeClassThatNeedsFunc:

```
// register a factory function to create a db context to be used in singleton classes
        services.AddTransient<Func<MyCustomContext>>(provider => (() =>
        {
            var dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyCustomContext>();
            dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);
            return new MyCustomContext(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
        }));
// register class that needs the factory:
        services.AddSingleton<SomeClassThatNeedsFunc>();
```

I get exception:

```
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
      Failed to process the job '4': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 3 of 10 will be performed in 00:01:55.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Func`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]' while attempting to activate 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Hangfire.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
   at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__0()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<PerformJobWithFilters>b__2()
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable`1 filters)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
   at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
```

Comment: Yeh, if you want to switch to hangfire just create a factory interface/class like so `interface IContextProvider<T>{ T GetContext();}` and then inject connection string to that class and have it return new contexts...

Comment: Looks like [MCVE] would be helpful... Exception and registration don't seem to have anything in common... At very least showing signature of `SomeClassThatNeedsFunc` would be nice.

Comment: @zaitsman I have switched to that now. I inject IOptions<AppConfig>,  where AppConfig holds a connection string, into my concrete implementation of IContextProvider<MyCustomProvider>. Now I can use that instead of the factory Func. However, hangfire still gives the same exception. Not only that, but it seems to be random, sometimes when I run it, it doesn't throw that warning, sometimes it does.. I'm starting to doubt that hangfire is a good idea.

Comment: @zaitsman I think I know why. I think HangFire is saving something to the db and is trying to do something based on the old code. The app works fine despite that exception.